# Python - Creating multiple lists within a list from slicing

Tags: python, list

I'm pretty new to coding in general and I'm having trouble cropping some of my data. It's in a simple text file and I so far have managed to take what is one big string of text from the file and split it into individual values within a list (e.g. index[0] = -78.5). The first two indexes in said list are latitude and longitude respectively, with the next 240 being values (the data that I want analyse). From there, the next two values are latitude and longitude again and so on - meaning indexes [242] and [243] are respectively latitude and longitude as well.

What I want to do is iterate through this list, taking out the first 242 indexes (lat, lon, and then the 240 individual values) and placing them into a list, which will then be put into a 'master' list, creating a nested list. I want to do this until I reach the end of the list, meaning I want to have a step of 242 (I think?). The end result should look something like this:

master_list = [[lat, lon, 240 values...], [lat, lon, 240 values...], ...]

I need this so that I can access each lat and lon individually while still keeping them associated with their values in that list, since I will be cropping this data based on coordinates.

So far, I have this:

```
f = open('file.txt', 'r')
file_contents = f.read()
f.close()

single_obs = file_contents.split(" ")
new_list = []
blank_value = single_obs[0]

def remove_blankspace(my_list):
    for i in my_list:
        if i != blank_value:
            new_list.append(i)
    return new_list
remove_blankspace(single_obs)

print new_list[0]
```

This is basically just me removing blank space from the file and making the string into individual elements in a list. 'new_list' has a lot elements!

I tried this as a test, but I was way off, and think I created an infinite loop since I had to restart my computer:

```
indiv_values = []

for value in new_list:
    line = new_list[::239]
    indiv_values.append(line)

print indiv_values[0]
```

I previously tried splitting it line by line, since each line contains the lat, lon and 240 values. I managed to create a list containing each line, but then can't separate every value in each line into individual elements.

Sorry if this is a terrible explanation or it's unclear what I'm trying to achieve (new to coding!), but just ask if anything is unclear!

Comment: I know it's frowned upon to suggest this, but your data sounds like something that could benefit from the third-party numpy library. Incidentally, slicing into 2d arrays is completely natural there, and efficient. You should consider taking a look at numpy arrays, they are very well suited to data-y stuff (as long as you have rectangular shaped nested lists).

Comment: @AndrasDeak: it's frowned upon for a poster to *ask* for on off-site reference, but there's nothing wrong with you offering it as a solution.  I up-voted.

Comment: @Prune thanks:) It's mostly frowned upon because it gets suggested way too often for no good reason, and it's a third-party library that's expensive to import when there are built-in tools that are appropriate. As others have put it, "numpy is the [jquery](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/313143) of python".

Comment: @T.Crawley: the entire file is one long input line, then?  No delimiter between data sets?

Comment: The file looks a bit like this:

Lon Lat value value value value (etc. until you have 240 values)
Lon Lat value value value value (etc.)
Lon Lat value value value value

So data for different coordinates (lat and lon values which are the first two values on each line) have 240 values on the same line (each corresponding to a year from 1860-2099, but aren't labelled). Individual values on each line are delimited by a blank space.

Sorry for the poor explanation, I'm still new to it all!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the file looks like:

```
lat1, lon1, values...
lat2, lon2, values...
...
```

And from what you describe you should be able to do:

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as fobj:
    file_contents = fobj.read()

llv = list()
for line in file_contents.strip("\n").split("\n"):
    data = line.split(" ")
    # process however you want
    llv.append([data[0], data[1], data[2:])
```

This will give you a list (llv) like the following:

```
[[lat1, lon1, [values...]], [lat2, lon2, [values2...]], ...]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I want to end up with a list that has values in the same list as each lat and lon, so; [[lat1, lon1, values, values, ...], [lat2, lon2, values2, values2, ...], ...]

The file also is comma delimited. It's delimited by blank spaces. Thanks for your help!